# How to apply regular expressions in React-native?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, react-native

When setting a nickname, I want to make the letter change true when I have to combine Korean or English letters with numbers without spaces, and when the letters of the nickname are 5 or more and less than 12 letters!

how can i fix my code? I don't know what i'm doing wrong.

```
               const Nickname = () => {
            const [nick, setNick] = useState('');
            const [letter, setLetter] = useState(false);

            const onChangeNick = useCallback((e) => {
                setNick(e.nativeEvent.text);
                const regex = /[\da-zA-Zㄱ-ㆌ]{5,12}/;
                if (
                regex.test(e.nativeEvent.text)
                ) {
                setLetter(true);
                } else {
                setLetter(false);
                }
            }, []);

            return (
                <Container>
                <NicknameContainer>
                    <Inputs placeholder="닉네임" value={nick} onChange={onChangeNick} />
                </NicknameContainer>
                </Container>
            );
            };

            export default Nickname;
```

Comment: change `const regex = [\S\d+]{5,12};` to `const regex = /[\S\d+]{5,12}/;`

Comment: @YosefTukachinsky i did but The letter changes to true even if there is no space or no combination of English and number.

Comment: There is no rule for combination of english and numbers in your regex, it accept any non space character. for english and numbers use `/[\da-zA-Z]{5,12}/`

Comment: If you want to include korean I think this should work `/[\da-zA-Zㄱ-ㆌ]{5,12}/`

Comment: how can i do that if i want to  Korean or English letters with numbers without spaces, and when the letters of the nickname are 5 or more and less than 12 letters? Even if i don't use regex?

Comment: so 5-12 is only letters, and also there should be at lease one number?
`/(?=.*[a-zA-Zㄱ-ㆌ]{5,12})(?=.*\d)^[\da-zA-Zㄱ-ㆌ]+$/`

Comment: @YosefTukachinsky    thank you Almost finished. However, the number are not counted. 
for example if i use your code ex: abcd1111 is false, (it suppose true) ,  abcd1111abcd (number are not counted): is true how can i count number?

Comment: you said you want 5-12 only letters, no? why then it suppose to be true?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/231792/discussion-between-user15322469-and-yosef-tukachinsky).